# Usage of "follow" followed by verb/without verb

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

I have taken a test and it was as follows:

> In mid-March, several European countries paused the distribution of
> the COVID-19 vaccine made by AstraZeneca, ------- that some people
> had developed blood-clotting disorders after receiving the jab.

and the options were:

> 1. following reports
> 2. following reports said
> 3. followed by the reports said
> 4. followed saying report

I had chosen the first one and that seems to be correct but I can not figure out Why are the second, third and fourth options are wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly, they're wrong because the sentences containing them are garbled gibberish.

2 is wrong because it should be "following reports *that* said" (or *which* said -- there will be discussion in the comments as to exactly which is correct).

3 is wrong for two reasons:

- a) to be grammatically correct, it should be "followed by the reports *that* (or *which*) said" (same as 2 above),
  and:
- b) it was because of the reports about blood clotting that distribution was paused. In the "followed by the reports (that) said" construction, it means that the reports were published *after* the distribution was paused, which is not what happened.

4 is wrong because it makes no grammatical sense and I can't manipulate into something which does. I will leave it up to someone else to explain that.